# VB - SQL - The 'replace' function renames the column

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, visual-studio, request

My SQL request was :

```
Dim cmd1 As New OleDbCommand("Select name, number, detailedliste from table1", conn)
Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
da.SelectCommand = cmd1
Dim FinalTable As New DataTable    
FinalTable.Clear()
da.Fill(FinalTable)
```

I had to replace some characters in the 'detailedliste' column.
So my request became :

```
Dim cmd1 As New OleDbCommand("Select name, number, replace(detailedliste,';',',') from table1", conn)
```

It works but it generates some errors when accessing the table in my code.
So I displayed FinalTab in a datagridviewv and I saw that the characters are correctly replaced but the column names are now : 'name', 'number' and 'Expr1007'

the 'detailedlist' column is now renamed as 'Expr1007'

Is it normal that the 'replace' request renames the column ? Maybe because it contains new data ? If so, is there a way to rename the column in FinalTable ?

Comment: `I had to replace some characters in the 'detailedliste' column` why? That's where the problems start. Storing a list of values in a field is a design bug to begin with. If an unexpected field separator appears it means there's a bug in the loading code. That needs to be fixed otherwise you'll end up mangling the data *as you just did*. `;` is used as a list separator by Windows in locales where `,` is the decimal separator. If your original value was `25,6;34;4` ie two decimals, you now have `25,6,34,4`, 4 integers and *no* way to recover the original data

Comment: Now, it is only text strings with detailed list of materials like : Laptop;keyboard;chair;lamp and instead of displaying it like this I would like something like : Laptop-Keyborad-chair-lamp. ',' or '-' or anything else would be ok, i just need to remove the ';'

Comment: I have tried replacing characters in other columns and it is the same result. It works but I have now 3 columns named 'Expr1007', 'Expr1008' and 'Expr1009'

Comment: `[...] replace(detailedliste,';',',') as detailedliste [...]`

Comment: I just find the same thing on another forum and you have confirmed this too. Thank you, it works !!!

Comment: Note that, depending on the underlying database, the Replace function may not handle null / empty values. You have an OleDb exception in that case and the query aborts. E.g., with an Access db, add `replace(detailedliste & '',';',',') as [alias]`

Comment: @Mika there's no point in that replacement to begin with. [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-7.0) has overloads that allow specifying multiple separators

Comment: @Mika as for the name, it's expected. Instead of returning `detailedliste` you're now returning an expression result with no name. Once again, the *serious* design bug of storing multiple values in a single field makes things a lot harder. If you had a separate `Details` table you could load *both* tables into a DataSet and display both as parent/child in the UI. This is how WinForms applications were built back in 2002.